# Dependency management in EAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, ear, modularity

We have following modularized structure in our project,

EAR 
  |
  |--- Web Module 
  |--- ConnectorFacade 
  |--- Connectors 
  |--- utility module 
  |--- BPEL module

there are other modules also for understanding problem i have mentioned few modules.

Currently any simple change happen in any one of the above mentioned module we need do the 
whole deployment on WebSphere application server since we have been archiving all modules in single EAR.

I wanted EAR should be separated from dependent module means apart from web module other modules should be outside EAR so that whenever any change happen in connector or any other module module i will just update connector jar and restart the App server it should pick new classes so that it will avoid my deployment process and i can ready with new changes in minimum time.

Let me know is there good solution to manage dependent jars.

Comment: Does you application server support hotdeploy of an exploded ear?

Comment: No my application does not support hot deployment.

Comment: Consider using one for development that does. It will save you quite a lot of time.

Comment: How about you write a build script which will package the jar and place this jar into the EAR file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by 'fnt' OSGI could be a solution for your issue.

What you could also do is, using remote EJBs.

Your remote service in a separately deployed jar

```
    @Stateless
    @Remote(MyRemoteInterface.class)
    public class MyService implements MyRemoteService {
      // Some implementations
    }
```

Shared api

```
    interface MyRemoteService {

    }
```

In some Module in your EAR

```
    @Stateless
    public class MyBoundary {
      @EJB
      MyRemoteService service;

      // Stuff
    }
```

For further information see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html)

Comment: Note that when calling remote beans all paremeters are serialized and deserialized, so there's a performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate solution for Websphere Application Server is to use OSGi Applications.

[Working with OSGi Applications (WAS 7.0)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.jpafep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/ta_ep.html)

[About OSGi Applications (WAS 8.0)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.osgi.nd.multiplatform.doc/topics/ca_about.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared libraries, but it's the dirty way to do it.
The other mode will be OSGI, but you should tweak all your logic, and it's a seperate mindset.

I don't see what will be the real benefits from isolating the build of your modules as long as you configure well your build tool, it will be matter of seconds.

Comment: I think you should concentrate on somthing like automated builds, hot deployment,...  not on spliting Your artifacts